# Random number generation in Openssl provider

Tags: openssl, cryptography, openssl-engine

I am trying to implement a openssl provider (say x-prov) with random number generation from HSM.
The x-prov provider during the initialization (in OSSL_provider_init function) uses the RAND_bytes api of openssl.

I execute the openssl command as
openssl rand --provider x-prov.so --provider default -hex 32

I am getting the following error

rand: unable to load provider x-prov.so
Hint: use -provider-path option or OPENSSL_MODULES environment variable.
4007CE76A07F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (CTR-DRBG : 0), Properties ()
4007CE76A07F0000:error:12000090:random number generator:rand_new_drbg:unable to fetch drbg:crypto/rand/rand_lib.c:571:

Can anyone help me solve the issue please ?

I am using OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

Loading the default provider at the start as -
"openssl rand --provider default --provider x-prov.so -hex 32"
will solve the RAND_bytes api issue,  But even the "openssl rand" command will get the random numbers from default provider. (wont use the x-prov.so for this).

Answer (score -1):

Use -provider-path to solve problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.